# How to COMPLETELY disable sleep/hybernate/faint/catchZZZs on Xubuntu 14.04

Tags: suspend

Today Xubuntu 14.04 screw me up yet another time. I tried to access my remote Samba only to figure out that my Xubuntu failed to stay awake. Luckily my Windows share worked as expected.

I've already followed suggestions on askubuntu such as
(1) set power management to never sleep
(2) disabled power management
(3) wrote some `.plka` file
(4) tried linking sleep to do nothing command

It all failed and Xubuntu keeps sleeping. Sudo apt-get upgrade to version 18.04 is not an option because I am not ready to invest in new hardware to fix a basic feature in a  "free OS".

Perfect solution would make sleep command destroyed, not "temporary turned off".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run some BitTorrent client with capped speed and (say 10 kB/ 8 connections max) sharing Ubuntu iso or something). This is the easiest reliable workaround on Fedora and Ubuntu.

I understand your frustration. An OS that fails to stay awake when ask it to is normally considered broken unless it is free... But you get security through obscurity. Cookie cutter attacks fail because every setup has its own set of broken services and diy fixes.

———————

Check your power management settings. If your power manager is disabled and removed from outruns Xubuntu still checks settings. Run the power manager service, make sure that sleep is set to never, restart, disable the service.

Comment: This didn't help. Neither did ping 127.0.0.1 I was hoping perpetual self-ping can help,m but Xubuntu doesn't care.

Comment: Indeed, PowerManager sleep was grayed out but set to 5 minutes.  Setting it to never and removing service from autostart solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Not just power management! You also have to disable the screensaver. By default, it blanks the screen and locks the screen (xubuntu). The screensaver settings interface has a link to the power manager interface at the bottom, but the power manager doesn't remind you that the screen saver exists.